# MSSQL. Сортировка в зависимости от порядка входящий параметров

Tags: sql-server, order

Есть процедура с несколькими входящими параметрами.В ходе процедуры выдается какой-то датасет. Один из параметров, который подается на вход, может состоять как из одного так и из нескольких значений.
Например:

```
 declare @var_name nvarchar(200)<br> 
 set @var_name = 'Bob Alex Piter'<br>
```

Как результирующий датасет отсортировать в зависимости от порядка значений в этой переменной?
Пример наглядного вывода:

```
ex1         ex2
Bob         Alex
Alex        Piter
Piter       Bob
```

Comment: *В ходе процедуры выдается какой-то датасет*, который нужно как-то отсортировать - и как на такой вопрос можно ответить? Добавьте к вопросу сам запрос, результат которого должен быть отсортирован.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT t1.value, 
                     CHARINDEX(t1.value, t2.txt) pos
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var_name, ' ') AS t1,
                   ( SELECT @var_name txt ) AS t2
            )
```

и далее JOIN по `value` и `ORDER BY pos`.

PS. Предполагается, что исходные данные не содержат косяков - вроде двойного пробела или дубликатов слов. Если же гарантии нет - следует допилить (добавить `WHERE RTRIM(value)<>''` и `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Спасибо. В данных только один пробел всегда. первая пачка двух колонок сортируется нормально. вторая пачка идет алфавит(я так понял). Буду разбираться дальше.